# Determine whether a function series is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Determine whether $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(jx)}{(2+x^2)^j}$ is uniformly convergent for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

So I started by saying as $|\sin(jx)|\le1$ so $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(jx)}{(2+x^2)^j} \leq \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2+x^2)^j} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{(2+x^2)})^j=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2+x^2}}=\frac{2+x^2}{1+x^2} $
So the function is pointwise convergent to the limit function $f(x)=\frac{2+x^2}{1+x^2}$

How do I now prove whether or not it is uniformly convergent? Thanks

Comment: Is $x\in \mathbb{R}$ here?

Comment: @Daniel yes sorry ill edit that in

Comment: $(\frac{1}{(2+x^2)})^j=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2+x^2}}$ is not true.

Comment: Your attempted solution is heading along the right lines - consider [the Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) and the bounds you've found already will serve you well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\bigg|\frac{\sin(jx)}{(2+x^2)^j}\bigg|\leq \frac{1}{2^j}$$ now use Weierstrass M-test.